# Alignment issue with input type='range' on chrome (webkit)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

I am having a bit of alignment issue with styling input range slider in chrome. It works fine on Firefox.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehLyhqwt/).

HTML :

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='box'></div>
    <input type='range' class='range'/>
</div>
```

I have given the box in the left for reference. In [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKcvA.jpg) the input control aligns vertically central against the box, while in [chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJN0M.jpg) it is aligned to the top.

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 80px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.box {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

input {
    float: left;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #b4b4b4;

}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 8px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #b4b4b4;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: 20px;
  width: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

I tried adding a margin-top for webkit, but it is giving a white patch on top as shown in this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehLyhqwt/1/). Not sure why.

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: You could add padding-top: 4px to the input{ padding-top: 4px; }

Comment: if you change the margin-top to 4px instead of 6px in input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{} class it looks ok

Comment: @JustinBreiland That will align perfectly in -webkit, but then will cause mis align in -moz. I could to apply padding only on -webkit, but that would be a hack. Like here http://phrappe.com/css/conditional-css-for-webkit-based-browsers/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ehLyhqwt/2/ - checked in both browsers

Comment: @RachelGallen Agreed, but for 1) Its not perfect, 2) Because of some reason, in my application this looks even terrible http://imgur.com/XbcPrrZ. I am not able to replicate this properly in fiddle :(

Comment: Using flexbox will also center it, .container { display: flex; align-items:center; }

Comment: @JustinBreiland That seems to do the trick! Browser support for flex might be an issue but for now this seems enough. Excellent, Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the float property from the input that you added in the css:

```
input {
  float: left; 
}
```

and it will work fine both in Chrome and Firefox.